# App running fine on Simulator, can't build on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I'm building an app in Swift 3 that sends out MQTT commands. The framework I use for this is `SwiftMQTT`. When I run the app on the iOS Simulator, it builds and runs without any errors. When I try to run it on my iPhone or archive it however, Xcode throws some weird errors. It finds the framework, but doesn't recognize the syntax.

As you can see, I have imported the **framework**:

[image]

These are the **errors** Xcode is throwing:

[image]

The framework is normally installed using CocoaPods, but something went wrong when using CocoaPods, throwing 30 errors in the framework itself. **I decided to import it manually**, but it just won't run on a real device..

What could be the cause of this? I sincerely have no clue..

Thanks in advance for any help, it really is appreciated!

**EDIT:**

[image]
[image]

**EDIT 2:**

I was able to fix this issue by updating my CocoaPods repo. I wasn't able to use CocoaPods beforehand because it would default to SwiftMQTT 1.0.0, but now I was able to install the Swift 3 SwiftMQTT 2.0.0 using CocoaPods.

Comment: Does the framework you are importing include an ARM binary?

Comment: Not that I know of. I just extracted the framework from their example project on GitHub, and it contains a header file and a main file.

Comment: Does the header file require any other imports?

Comment: Can you paste the build log? It will have more details.

Comment: @hotpaw2 I have edited the original question to include the header file and an image of what files the framework contains.

Comment: try to add this line  `@executable_path/Frameworks`  to `Runpath Search Paths` under `Build Settings`